# Start Java jar by service (linux) with parameters as a single variable

Tags: java, bash, shell

I want to start a jar file (Spring Boot app), with additional parameters.

It start normally when I start by shell command:

```
java -jar spring.boot.jar --parameter01="My Parameter Value 01" --parameter02="My Parameter Value 02"
```

Now, I want to pass all parameters into a bash shell (to start it as a service within /etc/init.d)

```
java -jar spring.boot.jar $1
```

($1 is equals value above >> --parameter01="My Parameter Value 01" --parameter02="My Parameter Value 02")

Then Spring app doesn't recognize the value "My Parameter Value 01", but only "My".
What should I do ? I tried to escape the space character and quote character, but nothing work.

Comment: I would suggest breaking the variable up into parts (`SENDER_NAME` and `PORT`), but your posted example should work. What operating system and shebang line are you using?

Comment: @RuaTre Please rephrase your question, right now it is almost not understandable.

Answer (score 1):

A simple script to call your `java -jar spring.boot.jar` with a single parameter, let's call it /etc/init.d/run-spring-boot, be sure to `chmod +x /etc/init.d/run-spring-boot` before executing it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo java -jar spring.boot.jar $1
java -jar spring.boot.jar $1
```

Invoke the script with a single input parameter of the entire string quoted and with escaped inner quotation marks:

```
/etc/init.d/run-spring-boot "--parameter01=\"My Parameter Value 01\" --parameter02=\"My Parameter Value 02\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try if your system supports systemd:

Create a service file with a name you consider is appropriate for you in the /etc/systemd/system/ directory:

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/spring-boot.service

[Unit]
Description=Spring Boot Service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=4
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/java -jar spring.boot.jar --parameter01='My Parameter Value 01' --parameter02='My Parameter Value 02'"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next you have to reload systemd:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Next you can start it:

```
sudo systemctl start spring-boot
```

Get status:

```
systemctl status spring-boot
```

Stop it:

```
sudo systemctl stop spring-boot
```

Or add it to autostart with system booting:

```
sudo systemctl enable spring-boot
```

To troubleshot you could run the next in parallel terminal window to see the realtime changes:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```